# opening a pdf file inside a pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor-pages

I am trying to open a pop up window that shows a pdf file inside it. The .pdf file resides in my wwwRoot folder. This is what I have:

```html
<div style="margin-top:100px">

    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('~/test.pdf',  'fullscreen=no'); return false;">MyPDF</a>
   
</div>
```

when I try to run the code, I get this error:

[image]

I have this code in my Home/Index.cshtml file. I tried to remove "~" and put the full path, but still the pdf file is not getting displayed. Below is my file structure. in below image, bottom most one in wwwRoot folder is the .pdf file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need ~, just "/test.pdf" on the client side.

~ is for server side code, so the client takes it as a folder name, as you can see on your popup url "localhost:64208/Home/~/test.pdf"

You can check more info about relative paths [in here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to put the entire path and partial and never removed "~"